# Smalltalk Pharo ZdcSecureSMTPClient not showing html formatting in GMail?

Tags: html, email, gmail, smalltalk, pharo

I'm using ZdcSecureSMTPClient to send an html formatted string to a gmail account. But when I send it it displays the html encoding as plain text. ie)

```
mailMessage := MailMessage empty.
mailMessage setField: 'subject' toString: 'Trying to send html '.
mailMessage body: (MIMEDocument contentType: 'text/html\n' 
                content:  '<html><head><b>  Dear   </b></head></html>'
```

This shows is Gmail as:   'html> head>  Dear   /b>/head>/html>'

Using Seaside/Pharo 2.0 one click image.

Answer (score 3):

What you use to set the mime type is not what is expected (additionally, the content of the message should be in `body`, not `head`). Use something like the following:

```
mailMessage := MailMessage empty.
mailMessage setField: 'subject' toString: 'Trying to send html '.
mailMessage addMixedPart: '<html><head></head><body><i>  Dear</i>   </body></html>' contentType: ZnMimeType textHtml printString.

ZdcSecureSMTPClient sendUsingGMailAccount: 'you@gmail.com' password: 'XXXXXXX' to: 'recipient@server.com' message: mailMessage.
```

You can check that your message is correct by sending the message `text` to your `message` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the swift and quick answers. I  found the solution to be adding the alternative part the message as below:

mailMessage := MailMessage empty. 
    mailMessage setField: 'from' toString: from.
    mailMessage setField: 'to' toString: to.
    mailMessage setField: 'subject' toString: subject.
    mailMessage addAlternativePart: textBody contents contentType: 'text/plain'.
    mailMessage addAlternativePart: htmlBody contents contentType: 'text/html'.

the link is: http://forum.world.st/Re-Seaside-dev-Accessing-service-from-a-mail-td4671547.html#a4672088